# How to filter a queryset using order clause on a subqueryset in django

Tags: python, django-models, django-orm

I have a base query which returns an ordered queryset and I am supposed to use that queryset as a filter for another but my second queryset is not returning in the same order.

Here is my code:

```
    queryset = ProductModel.objects.filter(
        id__in=SponsoredProductModel.objects.filter(
            product_id=self.request.parser_context['kwargs']['pk'],
        ).order_by('position').values_list('sponsored_product', flat=True),
    )
```

This is my ProductModel:

```
class ProductModel(basemodel.BaseModel):
    # relative fields
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    tax = models.ForeignKey(
        TaxModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    brand = models.ForeignKey(
        BrandModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True, blank=True
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(
        UnitModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True, blank=True
```

and this is SponsoredProductModel:

```
class SponsoredProductModel(basemodel.BaseModel):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='sponsored_base_product'
    )
    sponsored_product = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='sponsored_member_product'
    )
    position = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
```

I want my sponsored product model to be ordered by position and get products in the same order.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you please share the relevant models (`ProductModel` and `SponosoredProductModel`)?

Comment: i have added my models

Answer (score 0):

Ordering the list of values will not help, since teh database will simply filter these, not order these. But you do not need these at all.

You can simply order by the position of the `sponsored` products:

```
ProductModel.objects.filter(
    sponsored_member_product__product_id=self.request.parser_context['kwargs']['pk']
).order_by('sponsored_member_product__position')
```

this will thus both *filter* and *order* the object by a related model by following the `sponsored_member_product` relation (the `related_name` in the `ForeignKey`).

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `Model` suffix. Therefore it might be better to rename <s>`ProductModel`</s> to `Product`.